# Clone Rows in in table layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have the following my_layout.xml layout

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tlTable" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="1,2"  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"  >
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/trRow" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1" style="@style/showtext_style" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Row1" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
            <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/p2" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv3"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:text="0"   />
    </TableRow >
  </TableLayout>
```

I want to dynamically create 10 rows where all of them are clones of the first Row except that the text of the first textview of each row (namely tv1) to be changed to have the Row number. So it will be Row1, Row2 , Row3.....Row10

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code into separate layout :

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv1" style="@style/showtext_style" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Row1" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/p2" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv3"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:text="0"   />
```

And use this code to dynamic creation of table row by inflating this layout to table row

Comment: Can you elaborate more?  I mean do I put the code under LinearLayout in an xml. If you can ellaborate more (maybe with with additonal code) then  I can accept the answer :)

Comment: I figured it out, I created a seperate layout with TableRow being the the root layout and inflater. So Accepted for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ListView instead of your approach.

Comment: It is hard because it is already this tablelayout is inside a listview and I don't want to change the design that much

Answer (score 0):

Take one linearlayout in which you can put your row.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_nearest_aed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

then inflate your row file:

```
    private View getView(int position, int subPosition) {
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    TextView txtTitel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_titel);
    TextView txtSubTitel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_sub_titel);
    TextView txtType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_type);
    ImageView imgToDetail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_nearest_aed_img_toDetail);
    final TextView txtPosition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_position);
    LinearLayout layRaw = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lay_raw);
    final double distance = Double.parseDouble(Constant.arrayPin.get(position).get(subPosition).getDistance());
    imgToDetail.setVisibility((distance > 2000.00) ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);

    txtTitel.setText(Constant.arrayPin.get(position).get(subPosition).getAddress());
    txtSubTitel.setText(Constant.arrayPin.get(position).get(subPosition).getAreaOfBuilding());
    txtPosition.setText("" + position + "#" + subPosition);

    txtPosition.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] txt = txtPosition.getText().toString().split("#");
            Intent iDetail = new Intent(mContext, PinDeatil.class);
            iDetail.putExtra("position", txt[0]);
            iDetail.putExtra("sub_position", Integer.parseInt(txt[1]));

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

then Add in your linear layout :

```
      for (int i = 0; i < Constant.arrayPin.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Constant.arrayPin.get(i).size(); j++) {
        listNearestAED.addView(getView(i, j));
    }
        }
```

Comment: Not sure where all these variables coming from. I couldnt follow your solution